# Mixture model predictive distributions in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mixture-model

I distilled a problem I am having with mixture modelling in scikit learn to the following 1D example. Simply fitting a mixture model to a 1D density. I'm experiencing good performance using the simple GMM, but odd behaviour using the Variational or Dirichlet Process GMMs. Firstly the fit is very poor and secondly, the distribution inferred does not normalise (see code and image below).

This same behaviour is apparent in the example http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/mixture/plot_gmm_pdf.html. The probabilities returned by the GMM class approximately normalise, while those from the DPGMM do not. Normalisations were computed by appending the following line:

```
print np.sum(np.exp(-Z)) * (x[1] - x[0]) * (y[1] - y[0])
```

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rndn

import sklearn.mixture as skmix

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = rnd.randn(0.7 * 300, 1) - 5
X = np.vstack((X, rnd.randn(0.3 * 300, 1) * 0.3 + 3))

# gmm = skmix.GMM(2)
gmm = skmix.DPGMM(2)
gmm.fit(X)

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)
p = np.exp(gmm.score(x))

plt.hist(X, bins=50, normed=True)
plt.plot(x, p)
plt.show()

integral = np.sum(p) * (x[1] - x[0])
print integral
```

[image: DPGMM bad fit]

Comment: Unfortunately there are some numeric instability issues with the DPGMM and VBGMM currently. Try scaling your data to zero mean and unit variance, but it could be that there is a bug.

Comment: Same problem. The DPGMM returns a non-normalised probability density, while the GMM computes a correclty normalised density. I have posted it as a bug on the sklearn github.